# Meteor - Subscribe to same collection in two different routes, records carry over with latency

Tags: mongodb, meteor, latency

I have two routes, each subscribing to the same published collection with different queries.  When I introduce simulated latency with Meteor._sleepForMs(xxxx), the previous routes records are displayed on the new route until the new publication is ran.

Is this a problem with the latency simulation or the way I'm publishing and subscribing to the collection in routes?  I've tried separating into two sets of publications, same results.  Please advise.

UPDATE - Link to gist - https://gist.github.com/chasemb/40ecad2261e085795781

Comment: I assume you are not waiting on the subscriptions in your routes - is that correct?

Comment: I am not, you are correct.

Comment: The problem with using waitOn, it refreshes the entire set of subscribed records when I load more through infinite scroll pagination.